# Titanium Desktop can't find image resource in local filesystem? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, desktop, titanium

I'm assuming this must be a problem exclusive to Titanium Desktop, as I can't imagine why it's not working.

I have a function that retrieves the user's selected directory and then proceeds to display all files within the directory. Two variables are explicitly then added to the DOM: list items for each file within the directory, and an img whose source is based on the directory + "\folder.jpg".

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the "folder.jpg" cannot be found by Titanium. The files all display perfectly fine, and both "URLs" are parsed identically:

```
function pickMusicFolder (){
        var win = Titanium.UI.getCurrentWindow();

        win.openFolderChooserDialog(function(folderResponse) {
            var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(folderResponse[0]);
            var listing = file.getDirectoryListing();
            for (var i = 0; i < listing.length; i++) {
                if (listing[i].isDirectory()) {
                    // if the listing is a directory, skip over it
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    // otherwise, print the filename of the file to the #main content window
                    var songOnList = listing[i].nativePath();
                    var iconOnList = file + "\\folder.jpg";
                    var iconAlbum = iconOnList.replace(/\\/g,"/");
                    var songURL = songOnList.replace(/\\/g,"/");
                    $('#main ul').append('<li><a href="javascript:playSong(\'' + songURL + '\')">' + songURL + '</a></li>');
                    $('#main').append('<img src="' + iconAlbum + '" />');
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

As an example, using a directory currently on my desktop, the output courtesy of Chrome's Inspector is:

```
<img src="C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/All Our Tomorrows End Today/folder.jpg">
```

I've also tried keeping blackslashes, as well as replacing the spaces with underscores in the directory.

Anyone have any ideas why my images can't be located?

Comment: Do you have a live demo you could link to? How are you calling `pickMusicFolder()`?

Comment: Sorry, no live demo. pickMusicFolder is called using an event handler attached using jQuery. All of the existing functions and features in the code work flawlessly, it's just this stupid image for some reason cannot be located...